# How finish all open activity Correctly?

Tags: android

I have 3 activities. **Activity A** which leads to **Activity B**,  go back to  start **Activity C**. However,
I placed a button in **Activity C**.

When click button go  **Activity A** (new ) and finish **C** And **B**.

I am using the code below,

**Activity A:**

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent x=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
        x.putExtra("len_folder", length_folder);
        loop_thread=false;
        startActivity(x);
    }
});
```

**Activity B:** in Animation End

```
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        imag_trash.clearAnimation();
 imag_trash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 startActivity(new Intent(B.this,C.class));
 finish();
```

**Activity C:**

```
            end_process.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

           startActivity(new Intent(C.this,A.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

but I pressing Back  ,There is still activity C and Activity C doesn't finish.
I do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code as written below

```
 end_process.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

             startActivity(new Intent(C.this,A.class));
             finish();
         }
 });
```

If you want to close all other activities then use

```
end_process.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Intent i=new Intent(C.this,A.class);
             i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
             startActivity(i);
         }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this which will finish all previous activities when you starting the first one again.

Put the below code in your C activity

```
end_process.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```